# I am not able to get my facebook share button in my html page

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I was trying to have a facebook share button on my html page. I have added my code below and tell if there is any issue with this code.

```
enter code here
<html>
<head>
<script>

 window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
 FB.init({
appId: 'xxxxxxx',
xfbml: true,
 version: 'v2.5'
 });
};

 (function (d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s);
  js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  </script> 
 </head>

 <body>
 <div id="social" style="display:inline-block; padding-left: 10px">
 <div class="fb-share-button" data-         href="http://whatsyourexcuse.co/#!prettyPhoto" data-layout="button_count"/>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button#example

Comment: What have you done to check if there are any issues? Have you checked developer tools in your browser